# Firebase Cloud Functions Setup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

So I am currently trying to get cloud functions setup in our React project, but unfortunately, I am not having any success. I have installed Firebase CLI using npm install -g firebase-tools. I also have updated firebase-functions and firebase-admin to the latest version. After these things, one has to use the command in the terminal 'firebase login', but when I do this, this is what I get

```
$ firebase login
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1174
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\CB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\is-promise\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\CB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\is-promise\index.js from C:\Users\CB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\run-async\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename C:\Users\CB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\is-promise\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\CB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\is-promise\package.json.

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1174:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\run-async\index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

I have tried what it has recommended other than the changing the requiring code to use import() because I do not know how to get that to work.

Comment: What version of Node are you using?  I've seen this issue occur when you are on an outdated version.

Comment: I am using v12.16.1.  I had installed node js a little more than a month ago, so I do not know if it is outdated or if that is an issue

Comment: I have re-downloaded Node.js to the newest version and I am still getting this error

Answer (score 1):

So I think I figured out the issue.  After installing the newest version of Node.js, I ran npm install -g firebase-tools again and it added a few more things.  In order to do firebase login through the terminal, I had to put in firebase login --interactive